# I need help fixing my code for a secret door

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am creating a game in unity and I'm trying to make a collider and input based opening system and here is my code:

```
public class SecretDoor : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject secretDoor;

    public bool open;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        open = true;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
        {
            secretDoor.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        open = false;

        secretDoor.SetActive(true);
    }

}
```

It isn't opening or closing so I was hoping someone could help me.

Answer (score 2):

The check for an input would only occur when the player touches the door, you may want to look into [OnTriggerStay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html). **Warning!**  I would like to note that the wiki also states that this function does not run on every frame, which can hinder with such ability.

> Note that trigger events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a rigidbody attached. Trigger events will be sent to disabled MonoBehaviours, to allow enabling Behaviours in response to collisions.

```cs
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
        //check code here
}
```

This is with the guess that the open boolean is working as correctly(you should check if it is as you have set it to public.

**So the best way** it is probably the best to implement the input detection within the update function like this using the open boolean.

```cs
void Update(){
    if(open){
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T)){
           //Stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ChilliPenguin the boolean is working like expected but the door wont open when I click t but you don't need to do anything more I got it working. I just changed some things around and added new things my code is different now. Thank you though.